# How to Find the Sum of Array Type NSDecimalNumber

Tags: arrays, swift, sum, nsdecimalnumber

I'm building a budget app in Swift.

The NSDecimalNumber is **first** added to an array after an action (below).

**Then** the NSDecimalNumber is converted to CurrencyFormat for TableView, and appended to a separate string array.

How can I find the sum of the **first** NSDecimalNumbers array to create an Available Amount Label?

```
var adding: [NSDecimalNumber] = [5, 6, 5.55, 6.55, 1]
```

I tried this to convert the number into NSDecimal(addingAmount), and then append it to the above array (adding):

```
let addingAmount = NSDecimalNumber(string: textInput.text) / decimal100
    adding.append(addingAmount)
    println(adding)
    println(reduce(adding, 0, +)) // prints 15
```

Unfortunately, println(adding) works, but nothing is printed for the sum.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

If you just want the total sum of the first array then you can cast it to double and add them together with `map` and `reduce`.

```
var adding: [NSDecimalNumber] = [5, 6, 5.55, 6.55, 1]
let test = adding.map { Double($0) }.reduce(0, combine: +)
println(test) // prints out 24.1
```

Comment: this will not preserve the floating point value of NSDecimalNumber and should be used with extreme caution.

Answer (score 6):

This is because there is no definition of the binary operator '+' for the `NSDecimalNumber` type. So once you manually define the operator, you can do it.

```
func +(lhs: NSDecimalNumber, rhs: NSDecimalNumber) -> NSDecimalNumber {
    return lhs.decimalNumberByAdding(rhs)
}
```